# How do I sort a list that I have appended to in Python 3.3

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.3

I've been racking my brains trying to figure this out:

```
for line in test:
    x = line.split()
    y = int(x[1])
    x.append({"Average":str(y)})
    print(x)
```

What this does is that it attaches the line Average:y to, as an example, James 20 30 0 50
It would then print to the user `James 0 0 0 0 {Average: 0}`
This is my issue:
My text document contains multiple different names and numbers like this:

```
James 20 0 0 0 0
Harrison 7 0 0 0 0
George 9 0 0 0 0
```

I also made it to calculate averages if there is more than one number above 0.
When I append that Average:y, I want to sort the entire list depending on their 'y'
so if it was:

```
James 20 0 0 0 0 {Average: 20}
Harrison 7 0 0 0 0 {Average: 7}
George 9 0 0 0 0 {Average: 9}
Oliver 10 5 6 0 0 {Average: 7}
```

It would become:

```
Harrison 7 0 0 0 0 {Average: 7}
Oliver 10 5 6 0 0 {Average: 7}
George 9 0 0 0 0 {Average: 9}
James 20 0 0 0 0 {Average: 20}
```

I am unable to figure out how to do this as I append each line one by one so if I try to sort it using the sort command it does not work. What I do is  append the first line -> print it -> append the second line -> so on....
How could I sort this list based on the appended averages? Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 0):

Tested, hope it works. You can get more items playing with the append function.

```
test = ["Harrison 20 0 0", "George 40 0 0", "Zohan 30 0 0"]
foo = []
for line in test:
    x = line.split()
    y = int(x[1])
    foo.append({"Name":x[0],"Average":str(y)})
    print(x)
sorted_x = sorted(foo)
print sorted_x
```

Comment: keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: I have each line in the text file like : ['George', '40', '0', '0', '0','0' {'Average': '0'}] (new line)  ['Kim', '20', '0', '0', '0','0' {'Average': '0'}] and so on. How would I split this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're printing in the loop. Collate the results first, then sort, then print.

Comment: I'm confused on how I would go about this. If they were to run this code more than once that stored, sorted then printed, then wouldn't the code store their numbers + average twice? Then when printed, it would print their average twice and then three time if the code were to be run again. How would you solve that? Also how would you go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Multiple people would be using the code from one computer, hence the multiple names. They get tested separately. So in my above example the code would've been ran 4 times to get those values. Edit: I've only given a small part of my code which I couldn't figure out and that was necessary to hopefully fix my problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to delete the file after it's done all the sorting and printing?